# Android: AsyncTask giving "skipping x frames" warnings

Tags: android

Im trying to understand how threading works in Android.

I've created this `AsyncTask` class, but I still get this warning in my console:

`Skipped 295 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

#### LoadAnswersTask class

```
public class LoadAnswersTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<MessageItemModel>> {

    public interface LoadAnswersEventHandler {
        void onLoadFinished(ArrayList<MessageItemModel> answers);
    }

    protected LoadAnswersEventHandler event;

    public LoadAnswersTask(LoadAnswersEventHandler event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<MessageItemModel> doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            QuestionModel q = QuestionModel.getById(Integer.parseInt(params[0]));

            ArrayList<MessageItemModel> items = new ArrayList<>();

            for (AnswerModel answer : q.getAnswers()) {

                MessageItemModel messageItem = new MessageItemModel();
                messageItem.message = answer.getComment();
                messageItem.id = answer.getId();
                messageItem.parentId = answer.getParentId();
                messageItem.gender = answer.getGender();
                messageItem.name = answer.getName();
                messageItem.reply = (answer.getParentId() > 0);
                messageItem.email = answer.getEmail();
                messageItem.answer = true;

                items.add(messageItem);
            }

            return items;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Failed to load question", e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<MessageItemModel> messageItemModels) {
        this.event.onLoadFinished(messageItemModels);
    }
}
```

**I also tried this approach, which seems to work - well sort of as I have my items in a Fragment inside a viewpager - and it sometimes didn't load the answers, im suspecting it's because of the `WeakReference` combined with the viewpager causing event.get() to be null, but i'm really not sure...**

```
private static class LoadAnswersHandler extends Handler {
    private WeakReference<LoadAnswersEventHandler> event;

    public LoadAnswersHandler(LoadAnswersEventHandler event) {
        this.event = new WeakReference<>(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(event.get() != null) {
            event.get().onLoadFinished((ArrayList<MessageItemModel>) msg.obj);
        }
    }
}

private LoadAnswersHandler loadAnswersHandler;

// ...
protected void loadAnswers(final LoadAnswersEventHandler event) {

        loadAnswersHandler = new LoadAnswersHandler(event);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    QuestionModel q = QuestionModel.getById(question.getId());

                    ArrayList<MessageItemModel> items = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (AnswerModel answer : q.getAnswers()) {

                        MessageItemModel messageItem = new MessageItemModel();
                        messageItem.message = answer.getComment();
                        messageItem.id = answer.getId();
                        messageItem.parentId = answer.getParentId();
                        messageItem.gender = answer.getGender();
                        messageItem.name = answer.getName();
                        messageItem.reply = (answer.getParentId() > 0);
                        messageItem.email = answer.getEmail();
                        messageItem.answer = true;

                        items.add(messageItem);
                    }

                    loadAnswersHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(loadAnswersHandler, UPDATE_UI, items));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Failed to load question", e);
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }
```

Thanks!

- Simon